# can “makes" be with “is" as below?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence:

> The relationship the develops among the people from the common understanding in a multiracial community makes life in such a community ***is*** very exciting.

I think ***is*** should be deleted right?

Source: English study app, Essay, “Living in a multiracial community", 4th paragraph

Comment: Yes, ***is*** should be deleted. And below is spelled with one l. And the second *the* in your example sentence should probably be *that* instead. I did not vote to close your question, although I'm not arguing with the idea, either; because you should always present your own research with this sort of question. I don't think that proof-reading is allowed.

Comment: Why are you bellowing?  No need to shout!!

Comment: Also, it should be "that" not "the" in "The relationship **the** (sic) develops..."

Comment: I agree with @Bread, if this is copied exactly I would not take that essay as an example of good English. You could either delete the "is" you have highlighted, or alternatively change "makes" into "means", but there are still a number of problems with the sentence.